# .net satellite resource dll editor

Tags: .net, winforms, resources, editor, satellite-assembly

Is there any free resource editor to edit compiled .net managed assemblies?

One of my clients requested to edit texts on windows forms controls of their app. I put all texts(strings) in a separate resource file. I can edit them in Visual studio but for the client to edit them, I guess they must be able to decompile the dll and edit resulted rc files and then compile them back again which I am not going to suggest cause it's too much hassle.

I was wondering if any resource file editor exists that can do it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource editor that you can try is
http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/
This is used mostly for multi language resources but its free and lets you edit the resource files, you would just have to complie the resource afterwards

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an **editor** for .NET assemblies, but [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3262/A-NET-assembly-viewer) is a very nice **viewer** of all the info found inside the assembly.